# google login with firebase results in "url != null" error when fetching profile data

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using the firebase_auth package to integrate google login method in my app. But when i navigate the login method to the profile page which fetches the google profile, i get the "url != null" error. 
Previously the same method worked, but somehow this method started to show error. Can anyone point to the actual mistake?
This is the error I'm getting

```
I/flutter (17443): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 23 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
```

this is the google_signin process.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:odoo_api/odoo_api.dart';
import 'package:odoo_api/odoo_api_connector.dart';
import 'package:odoo_api/odoo_user_response.dart';

var id;
String name;
String email;
String imageUrl;
String phone;
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);
  assert(user.photoUrl != null);
  // assert(user.phoneNumber != null);
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  imageUrl = user.photoUrl;
  // phone = user.phoneNumber;

  if (name.contains(" ")) {
    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
  }

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

Future<bool> signOutGoogle() async {
  await _auth.signOut();
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Sign Out");
  return true;
}
```

this method is triggered when clicking a button

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                height: 45,
                child: SignInButton(
                  Buttons.Google,
                  text: "Sign In with Google",
                  onPressed: () {
                    signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() async {
                      // createContact();
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return FirstScreen();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

the "First_Screen" is the profile page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/components/side_drawer.dart';
import 'package:my_project/pages/delivery/delivery.dart';
import 'package:my_project/pages/login/login.dart';
import '../../google_sign_in.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [Colors.blue[100], Colors.blue[200]],
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  imageUrl,
                ),
                radius: 80,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Text(
                'NAME',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black87),
              ),
              Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                'EMAIL',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black87),
              ),
              Text(
                email,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  signOutGoogle();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return LoginPage();
                  }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                },
                color: Colors.red[900],
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Log Out',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("User Profile"),
        leading: IconButton(
          tooltip: 'Previous choice',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            print('button clicked');
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => new DeliveryPage(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```